# python extract a file from inside a .tar file that is inside .tar.gz file

Tags: python

i can manually extract a .tar file that is inside of a .tar.gz file, then manually open or extract a single file from the .tar file.  Is there a method to open the .tar.gz file (which only contains another single file that is .tar) then call for a single file to be extracted from the .tar file that is inside of the .tar.gz file?

Comment: Did you look at the [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module?

Comment: yeah i tried 'r:gz' that wouldn't work well i ended up using gzip and then tar, i was hoping to use just 1 or the other, i know alot of apps like 7zip can just auto handle .tar inside of a tar.gz or .gz,